# How to print frequency of dice vertically

Tags: python-3.5

The following code needs to print like this:

```
Face frequency
1 * 
2 * * * 
3 * * * * 
4 * * * 
5 * * * * * * * 
6 * * * * * * *
```

The number marking the number, and the asterix marking the frequency at which that number has appeared.

```
        print ("Face frequency")
        index = 1
        while index<len(die_count):
            print (index, end = " ")
            for k in range (0, die_count[index]):
                print ("*", end = " ")
            index += 1
```

This is the code, but it prints like this:

```
Face frequency
1 * 2 * * * 3 * * * * 4 * * * 5 * * * * * * * 6 * * * * * * *
```

How do I get it to print the way as first shown?

Comment: Other than printing a newline?

Comment: Problem solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely you just use print a new line? Can be done using `/n`.